# how to unset and destroy only one session variable

Tags: php, web, session

Using PHP, consider that I have many active session variables, and I want to destroy and unset a specific one.
the session variable name is `$_SESSION['panel'];`

I used `session_unset($_SESSION['panel']);` but it doesn't work

**PS:** I don't like to use `session_destroy()`, because it destroys all other session variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php) states that if `$_SESSION` is used you should unset it using `unset($_SESSION['var'])`

Answer (score 0):

If you have to unset the specific session variable then use this one unset($_SESSION['panel']); it will work